# How this toy shown on YouTube works and can the coil be replaced by a hollow magnetic thorus?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, batteries

I saw [this video on YT](https://youtu.be/J9b0J29OzAU) and what I can not figure out is why the coil used in the arrangement could not be replaced by a hollow magnetic torus?

Comment: what is a "hollow magnetic torus" the coil is not magnetic, parts of the coil in contact withe the ends of the batterie  get magnetic by the current.

Comment: @trula Is the cause of movement of the toy nothing else than interaction between magnetic fields of the monopole and coil?....so someone can conclude that also a thorus can produce a magnetic field to interact with the monopole...

Comment: it is the traveling magnetic field, induced by the battery between the two poles, there is no monopole. In a closed torus, the current would not flow around, but in the direction of the train.

Comment: @trula Sorry, but when I say monopole I think of magnets attached to the battery being in opposite directions... eg. one side is a north pole and the second either...

Comment: no, the batterie with the magnets on it has a north and a south pol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the magnets are attached to the ends of a battery (the source of power).  To experience a net force, the magnets must be in a non-uniform magnetic field. In this case the magnets conduct current, to the coil, which flows only between the magnets.  A short segment of hollow magnetic torus produces a field which spreads rapidly at the ends and thus exerts a force on the magnets which are at each end of the energized segment. One would need to be careful that the magnets are oriented so that both forces are in the same direction. In this system, the current is mainly limited by the internal resistance of the battery, and may be relatively large. The battery will be drained quickly.  A magnet acts as though it has a current flowing around its outer surface.  If we take a side view and assume that the field from the coil is spreading out from its right end (the “north pole”), and we place a magnet so that its current flows away from us on the top (putting its north pole on the left), then the vertical component of the field will push the current on top of the magnet to the right, and the current on the bottom will also be pushed to the right. (This kind of analysis can also be applied to the microscopic currents associate with each atomic dipole using the divergence of the field).  On the left end of the activated section of the coil, the field is coming in, the vertical components are reversed, and to keep the net force to the right, the magnet would need to be reversed.  If you think of both magnets as being just outside of the ends of the activated coil, the north pole of the magnet is being repelled by the north pole of the coil on the right, and the north pole of the magnet is being attracted by the south pole of the coil on the left. (A compass needle can be used to determine which ends are north or south.)

Comment: Is that the magnets are in opposite direction so one is being attracted by the coil magnetic field and the other one goes away making the toy moving along the coil?

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I will study Your answer before accepting... because it seems little bit tricky to understand quickly....